# c# getters setters style

Tags: c#, properties, private, setter, getter

I'm working on some code where there is lots of code like this:

```
private int x;

public void SetX(int new_x)
{
   this.SetXValue(new_x); 
}

private void SetXValue(int new_x)
{
   this.x = new_x; 
}
```

and similarly with properties:

```
private int x;

public int X 
{
    get { return this.GetX(); }
}

private int GetX()
{
    return this.x; 
}
```

What i don't get is why the need for the private methods which do the actual work, i.e. why not just have methods like this instead:

```
public void SetX(int new_x) 
{
  this.x = new_x;
}

public int X
{
    get { return this.x; }
}
```

is it just the other persons personal choice or is there some good reason for using the first way?

(i typed above code manually so sorry if any mistakes but you should hopefully see what i'm trying to say)

Cheers
 A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason for code like that as far as I can see. If you're not doing anything with the new values (like processing/checking before storing) and you're writing C# 3.0 you can actually just shorthand it it to this:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

The compiler creates the backing store for you and you can just reference:

```
this.MyProperty
```

...inside your class. You can also create get-only properties like:

```
public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
```

All of which I think is pretty neat!

Comment: While this is nice I fail to see how this answers the question. The question was if there was a reason for having the private methods and the simple answer is: no, there isn't.

Comment: When I switched to writing C#3 code (and since then 4) all of my code got neater and more expressive. They introduced some really nice language features that allow you to keep things tidy and readable - this is just one of those examples.

Comment: @PatrikHägne - Agreed! Edited!

Comment: @PatrikHägne Actually the very first line addresses this, might be its not so obvious but really its addressing the question. *not doing anything with the new values ..*

Comment: Actually I try to use the above style of properties as well, occasionally for some reasons in this code there are mutable structs (i know bad!) so they have an underlying private member which is set via this property get / set..anyway good to know there's no good reason for the separate private getter/setter i can clean up the code a bit!

Comment: From a functionality point of view, no there is no reason to write in that mode. But a thought come to my mind. *!!!!Obfuscation!!!!*. A private method will be aggressively mangled by an obfuscator, when a public one is more difficult to hide.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Getters and Setters directly to implement your logic? I don't understand the need for additional methods unless you have extra parameters that influence the setter's behavior:

```
    private int myVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get 
        { 
            return myVar; 
        }
        set 
        {
            myVar = value; 
        }
    }

    public void SetMyPropertySpecial(int a, string reason)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyProperty was changed because of " + reason);
        this.myVar = a;
    }
```

Update:

Indeed, this person seems to like having more lines of code, but the structure is utterly useless. Stick to .NET standards using Getters and Setters (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx))

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no reason for doing this, it looks liks someone was paid by lines of code.

So, yes, you're right, this is just the other persons personal choice, and it's not a very good one.

Answer (score 1):

I think it must be an old Java developper that did this.

The .Net way is

```
private int _foo;

public int Foo
{
     get
     {
         return _foo;
     }
     set
     {
          _foo = value;
          dostuff();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb is to use properties for simple get/set operations and get/set methods when there is a relevant part of logic needed to get/set a value (e.g. validation during set or database access during get).

So if the actual code is really as simple as in your example just use properties and do the work in their getters/setters.

If the actual code is more complex replace the properties (at least the setters) by methods as in your third example.

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason would be that the properties can have login that should be executed only when the property is set externally and calls from inside the class do not execute the whole logic but only the logic in the private method. Of course it makes no sense to make these methods in advance because introducing them later will not change the contract of the class. Chances are that whoever wrote this code was new to C# and did not understand what properties do.

Answer (score 0):

That's very bizarre, there's no justifiable reason for doing that. Please refactor that code. There's also no need for a `SetX` method as setter can be included in properties. e.g.:

```
public int X {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 0):

i may be missing something here, but this looks a bit mad to me!

You can achieve the same by either using automatic properties or properties with backing fields.  here's a good description of both: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/12/04/c-3-0-features-automatic-properties.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is fine only if the `SetValue` is `private` or `protected` and is doing more than just setting a value.

I am working on a project where we do a lot of those things. That is because we are doing more than just setting a value (value checks, state checks etc.)
Having a public setter and a public `SetValue` does not make sense at all and will confuse your consumers as to what setter to use.

Here is another scenario where we use this kind of design:

```
public abstract class A{
   protected virtual void SetValue(object value);
   public object SomeObject{
      set{SetValue(value);}
   }
}
```

In this case, we want class `A` to delegate setting/checking that value to whatever class inheriting from it.